# Huawei Matebook 16 randomly freezes

Tags: kernel, touchpad, freeze, amd-processor, huawei

I got a Huawei Matebook 16 (see [specs](https://consumer.huawei.com/uk/laptops/matebook-16/specs/)) back in October 2022, so I've used it for about 4 months now without problems. I removed Windows and set up Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I'm a software developer and I don't use it for very intense processing.

Recently however the touchpad would randomly stop working. This seems to be a fairly common issue but didn't bother me massively. I would save whatever I was doing and reboot. There are also ways to set shortcuts to restart the touchpad (see [here](https://github.com/zer0nka/linux-on-huawei-matebook-d-14-amd#Touchpad), although I hadn't gotten around to setting that up)

More recently it got worse and now Ubuntu will freeze completely, often leaving the mouse cursor active, but nothing else.

I am not a savvy Ubuntu user, don't know how to debug these things.

[A thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/fwiuf4/my_huawei_matebook_freezes/) indicates other users have had problems with Ubuntu on their Matebooks and that kernel parameter tweaks might solve this.

[One Github repo](https://github.com/zer0nka/linux-on-huawei-matebook-d-14-amd) with feedback on how their 2018 Matebook 14 and Ubuntu got along suggests the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="vga=current ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2 idle=nomwait acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2015' acpi_enforce_resources=lax scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1"
```

and if I break that down there is:

- `vga=current` : don't know what this does
- `ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2` : no idea what this does
- `idle=nomwait` : according to [the manual](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/admin-guide/pm/cpuidle.html) "The idle=nomwait option disables the intel_idle driver and causes acpi_idle to be used (as long as all of the information needed by it is there in the system’s ACPI tables), but it is not allowed to use the MWAIT instruction of the CPUs to ask the hardware to enter idle states." which seems like a good idea when not using an Intel cpu, but is this likely to be causing the freezes?
- `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2015'` : this seems to be erasing the current value of acpi_osi and replacing it with Windows 2015, I am guessing to try to fool the BIOS into thinking it's running Windows? No idea why this would be a good thing to do.
- `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` : this seems like a potentially risky tweak judging by the [results when I google it](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=265939)
- `scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1` : seems like a very under the hood setting to change how HDDs are accessed - pretty sure this can't be useful for me

Another user who [cloned the above repo](https://github.com/All3xJ/linux-on-huawei-matebook-d-14-amd#Touchpad) had a different suggestion for parameters, but he indicated that the freeze happens during intensive tasks - which hasn't necessarily been my experience.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="idle=nomwait iommu=pt"
```

- `iommu=pt` : no idea what this does, information I found was on [NVIDIA site](https://enterprise-support.nvidia.com/s/article/understanding-the-iommu-linux-grub-file-configuration)

So my question here is, is there anything fairly obvious I can try to fix this or do I need to gather more information about what is causing Ubuntu to freeze up or even, do I just have to resign myself to the fact that Huawei and Ubuntu don't get along?

Comment: hey there, wanted to know if it is a Huawei Matebook 16 with AMD Ryzen 5600H - I am being bit by the trackpad bug on openSUSE and Fedora (where, by the way, I have no freezing issues you have described, so maybe you could try out to find out if it is an ubuntu bug or a hardware bug)

Comment: hi
no it's a AMD Ryzen 7 5800H.
I get the trackpad bug as well. I experimented a bit with GRUB parameters, but what it turned out to be I think is Slack installed with snap.

It kept freezing up. I've uninstalled Slack by snap and everything is fine. Except for the  trackpad occasionally stopping working.